# MS Access - recordset not updateable on subform

Tags: t-sql, ms-access

I have an ms database that uses a tsql backend - in this subform it creates a row in the table no problem but I can't add any text to the text field in the form- Access displays 'Recordset not updateable'. I can manually change data in the linked table and I can also delete rows, but once in the form I can not delete as it is saying the database is 'read only' ? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Under design view, look at the forms 'data' properties, make sure the 'allow additions/edits' say yes.

Answer (score 0):

The error was down to a primary key not having been deleted on a linked table.